# grailsChange issue in db migration plugin

Tags: hibernate, grails, database-migration, grails-3.0

I'm using the `database-migration:2.0.0.RC1` with Grails 3.0.8. Here is example of failed change set:

```
changeSet(author: '...', id: '...') {
    grailsChange {
        change {
            final BATCH_SIZE = 500
            long offset = 0

            def loadBatchVers1 = { Class clazz ->
                clazz.findAll("from ${clazz.simpleName}", [], [max: BATCH_SIZE, offset: offset])
            }


            SessionFactory sessionFactory = ctx.getBean("sessionFactory")
            def loadBatchVers2 = { Class clazz ->
                Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.currentSession.createCriteria(clazz)
                criteria.setFirstResult(offset)
                criteria.setMaxResults(BATCH_SIZE)
                return criteria.list()
            }

            // Load domain objects using loadBatchVers1 or loadBatchVers2 and make changes in db
         }
     }
}
```

when I'm using `loadBatchVers1` to load domain objects, here is the exception I'm receiving:

```
 Method on class [XXXX] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

I think that it's probably because I'm using static method `findAll` of domain class, so I implemented version `loadBatchVers2`.
Exception for `loadBatchVers2`:

```
Error: No Session found for current thread
```

I can't make any changes inside **grailsChange** section of **changeSet** using static domain methods or hibernate criteria api.

Comment: What kind of changes do you want to make?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal, just call some methods on domain instances.

Comment: Okay, but what exactly happening in that method? I mean, are those methods trying to do something like sending an email?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal, no, nothing special, it just recalculates object's property. The real problem here is static method call - findAll, I tried to avoid it using criteria api, but it doesn't work too.  I had the same problem with integration tests before, I had to use spring `@Transaction` annotation to make them work.

Comment: If it's not an overhead for you then can you please create a sample app on GitHub because this seems to work fine for us in Grails 2.5.x

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal, I will try, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal, sorry for delay, but as I said, I have this problem in Grails 3.0.x app. And this is happens because GORM stuff is not yet ready, the earliest time you can reliably call GORM methods is at `BootStrap.groovy`. So the workaround is to start dbm-update task of db migration plugin from Bootstrap.